# Partitioning polynomials over a finite field based on acting identically on the field elements

Tags: polynomials, graph-theory, finite-fields

I think you could phrase this question purely algebraically in terms of $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$ acting on $\mathbb{F}_q$ by evaluation, but since $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$ doesn't form a group under composition I wasn't sure how to do that properly. Instead I formulated it in terms of graph theory.

> Given a polynomial $f \in \mathbb{F}_q[x]$, we can define a labelled directed graph $G_f$ with vertices $\operatorname{V}(G_f) = \mathbb{F}_q$ and with edges $\operatorname{E}(G_f)=\{a \to f(a) \mid a\in\mathbb{F}_q\}$. Such a graph must be a [functional graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/280717/167197). For which $g \in \mathbb{F}_q[x]$ are the graphs $G_f$ and $G_g$ isomorphic? What about isomorphic up to relabelling of vertices? In general, how does $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$ become partitioned under this relation based on acting "identically" on the underlying field elements?

I would hope that there is something nice and clean that can be said to answer this question, but otherwise I would be quite happy with some references to similar research, or even just some *vocabulary* to Google to learn more about problems like this.

Comment: See e.g. Konyagin et al. [Functional graphs of polynomials over finite fields,](http://comp.mq.edu.au/~bmans/BMans/Papers/JCT_B_KLMMSS2016.pdf) Jnl. Comb. Th. B, (2016) 87-122.

Comment: @MorganRodgers you could require that the isomorphism preserves the labelling of the vertices too. It's just the difference between the graphs being isomorphic, and the graphs being isomorphic **and** the field elements that represent each vertex being preserved under the isomorphism. One just provides a finer partitioning of $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$.