# Graph isomorphism between two functional graph.

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/280721/1265344), I could understand what a functional graph is. But how can we find a function $f$ such that f is an isomorphism between two fuctional graph, $H$ and $G$ given by fuctions $h(x)$ and $g(x)$ respectively.

To avoid deciding upon whether those graphs are isomorphic or not let us assume that both graphs are cycles of length $n$. And as far as I can think about is that two cycles of same length must be isomorphic.

Comment: I don't even know that it makes sense to talk about an isomorphism between functional graphs, or about a functional graph being a cycle of length $n$. What exactly are you trying to ask here?